# Adding a column to a table in R

Tags: r

I need to add a column to a table, but the values of the new column depend on the values in another column. For example, I would need H45E4 to become "bag" (this is not the exact thing but the same concept). I cannot use the dplyr ifelse or other functions because it is not a condition based thing. Does anybody have any suggestions?